# duda en campos de bits

Tags: c

Tengo este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * palabra de 32 bits: 0 a 31
 */
struct palabra {
    unsigned car_ascii      : 7; // bits 0 to 6
    unsigned bit_paridad    : 1; // bit 7
    unsigned operacion      : 5; // bit 8 a 12
    unsigned                : 18; // bits 13 a 30 de relleno
    unsigned bit_signo      : 1; // bit 31
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    struct palabra cb = { 'C', 1, 0x1E, 0 };

    printf("campos de bits: %x\n\n", cb);
}
```

El resultado es 1ec3
Es decir:
0001 1110 1100 0011

Con mas cuentas que hago no me sale.

Alguien puede aclararme como funciona esto.

Gracias de antemano

Un cordial saludo

Comment: Tanto el compilador como la arquitectura para la que compilas se encargan de manejar esos campos de bits, no siempre se ordenan como quieres... te recomendaría utilizar masks y shifts.

Answer (score 2):

La estructura en memoria queda así:

```
| 00 | 00 | 01 | .. | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 
| bs | relleno ...  |       operacion        | bp |        car_ascii                 |
```

Y tu estás guardando los siguientes valores:

```
| 00 | 00 | 01 | .. | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 
| bs | relleno ...  |       operacion        | bp |        car_ascii                 | 
|  0 |  0 |  0 | .. |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
```

Y si los agrupamos en hexadecimal...

```
| 00 | 00 | 01 | .. | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 
| bs | relleno ...  |       operacion        | bp |        car_ascii                 | 
|  0 |  0 |  0 | .. |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 | 
|     0  ...   |    1    |         E         |         C         |         3         |
```

¿De dónde sale cada valor?

- operación: `0x1e` es, en binario: `0001 1110`. Como el campo donde se almacena el valor ocupa 5 bits se descartan los 3 de mayor peso, quedano `1 1110`
- bit de paridad: `1`. No hay mucho que explicar
- car_ascii: `C`, que se traduce al número (ver tabla ASCII) `43` en hexadecimal o, en binario, `0100 0011`. Como el campo ocupa 7 bits hay que descartar el bit de mayor peso.

Esto es suponiendo una máquina *big endian*. En una máquina *little endian* la agrupación de bits se verá alterada y el resultado mostrado en pantalla variará.